# Inside a where clause: Casting a substring as a date only when IsDate() is true

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to delete all rows that are older than 6 months from a table.

The issue is that the date is grabbed using a substring from a varchar column, and it is not always a valid date.

Here's the query that is failing:

```
Delete ExampleDatesTable
 where CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateField, LEN(DateField) - 18, 19)) < DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

Here is what I am trying to do, but it isn't working:

```
 Delete ExampleDatesTable
 where IsDate(SUBSTRING(DateField, LEN(DateField) - 18, 19)) = 1
 AND CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateField, LEN(DateField) - 18, 19)) < DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?   What do you want to do with the rows that aren't valid dates?

Comment: If the rows aren't valid dates, then skip them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select valid records first.. then delete based on date.

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM ExampleDatesTable
    WHERE ISDATE(SUBSTRING(DateField,LEN(DateField) - 18,19)) = 1
)
DELETE  data
WHERE   CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(DateField,LEN(DateField) - 18,19)) < DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())
```

Comment: If I want to add a check for if the DateField's length is larger than 19 before I call the SUBSTRING function, do you recommend using another With As () statement

Comment: i would just make it part of the where in the `data` cte